# Sorting function for multiple measures in QlikSense

Tags: function, if-statement, data-visualization, qlikview, qliksense

Hi for starters i'm new to QlikSense and QlikView.
I am trying to display dynamic charts that changes based on measure sorted in a descending order (On user click it changes based on the measure). Does anyone know the function for sorting a dynamic chart? 
Edit: my chart is bar chart that has a measure and alternative measure

I have tried running a count function to sort but it will only sort one chart. some thing like if user clicked on chart X to be displayed then sort by X function, if user clicked on chart Y to be displayed then sort by Y function.

my expression logic:
if(LabelName = label_name then count(X) else count(Y))

Any tips and tricks are appreciated.

Comment: On the sort tab you need to select "Sort by Y value"

Comment: @TheBudac thank your for the reply.  I am working on sorting Y axis as i don't get the function option in the X axis. What i did is that i have two measure to that changes values of the graph as user decides one that shows the total of sales per year and another shows quantity of sold items. i want to sort values in a descending order.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:
If you have multiple dimensions in a bar graph (Measures and Alternative measures)
sort them using this code:
if(GetObjectMeasure()= Label Name ,do this expression,else expression)